# Making a menu with icons in Tkinter

Tags: python, menu, tkinter

Sorry I didn't really know how to title this.

I need to create a bar for my Tkinter application so that users have single click access to functions like open, save, and save as. Ideally this bar would have icons to go with it. This is for a text editor if that helps.

I've looked around for quite a while but I'm only finding information on drop down menus rather than the kind I am trying to create.

This needs to run multi-platform if possible, but at the very least on Mac.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This normally does the trick for me:

```
menu.add_command(label="Description", image=iconPhotoImage, compound="left")
menu.iconPhotoImage = iconPhotoImage
```

Where iconPhotoImage is a PhotoImage. In my experience the images can get a little squashed until they're mouse-overed.